# AngularJS scripts not working when outside of immediate file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am doing a AngularJS tutorial which comprised of an HTML file and a simple JS script to provide simple Angular functionality. The following is the HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    <head>
        <title> Angular Practice </title>
    </head>

    <body ng-app='learningAngular' ng-controller='myCntr'>

        <input type="text" ng-model='name'> <br>

        <div ng-bind='name' ng-click='alertMe()'></div>
        <button ng-click='alertMe()'>Alert Me Angular</button> <br>
        <div ng-show='willShow'> Show this!! </div>
        <button ng-click='toggleShow()'> Show </button>
        <div ng-hide='willShow'> using ng-hide! </div>

        <ul ng-repeat='puppy in doggos'>
            <li> {{ puppy }} </li>
        </ul>

        <ul ng-repeat='(student, grade) in grades'>
            <li> {{ student }}, {{ grade }} </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The script, main.js, which lies in the same folder, looks like this:

```
    var app = angular.module('learningAngular', []);
    app.controller('myCntr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Josephine';
        $scope.alertMe = function() {
            alert("Congrats!");
        };
        $scope.willShow = true;
        $scope.toggleShow = function() {
            $scope.willShow = !$scope.willShow;
        };
        $scope.doggos = ['rex', 'fido', 'rover'];
        $scope.grades = {
            Max: 'A',
            Joan: 'B',
            Jay: 'C'
        };
    }]);
```

I am very confused because when I have the Angular module/controller in the script file (main.js) in the same folder, Angular no longer works. When I move the script into index.html, it works perfectly fine. I have tried messing around with the src='main.js' to see if that was the problem, and couldn't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Try moving your script tags to the end of the body element.

Comment: @JCFord Thank you! That seems to work. Do you know why that would matter?

Answer (score 1):

Your `<script>` tag should be inside your `<head>` or `<body>` tag. That might be why it's not picking it up.

Something like this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Angular Practice </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app='learningAngular' ng-controller='myCntr'>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The old convention was to put scripts at the end of the `<body>` tag, but since we're working with a Javascript framework that is responsible for rendering the view, that convention doesn't make sense anymore.